# PyGame Poor Image Quality & Gradient Banding

Tags: image, pygame

I noticed that when displaying jpg or png images they look alot like a GIF file in that there is limited colors and "banding".

You can see the original and a screenshot attached. Kinda hard to tell scaled down but you can see it.

[image: Original Image]
[image: Screen Shot]

Actually better example. See the banding around the circle?
[image: Better example]

Here is my code:

```
#pygame code to render an image
import pygame, os
import time
image = 'gradient-test.png'  #located in same folder as this file:resized in Photoshop 
pygame.init()  #I assume you did this?
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((1366, 768))
pygame.mouse.set_pos((1366, 768))
picture = pygame.image.load(image)
SCREEN.blit(picture,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Have you tried the third argument in set_mode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with the pixel format of your surface. You can add the following lines to your script to see if there's a difference between the pixel format of your image surface and your screen surface:

```
print 'picture', picture.get_bitsize()
print 'screen', SCREEN.get_bitsize()
```

It's good practice and recommended to always change the pixel format of any new surface to the pixel format of your screen surface by calling [`convert()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert):

> **convert()**
>
> *change the pixel format of an image*
> `convert(Surface) -> Surface`
>
> Creates a new copy of the Surface with the pixel format changed ...
>
> If no arguments are passed the new Surface will have the same pixel format as the display Surface. This is always the fastest format for blitting. It is a good idea to convert all Surfaces before they are blitted many times.

It's simple:

```
picture = pygame.image.load(image).convert() # added convert() call
```

Also, you can try to set the color depth of your screen manually, like:

```
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((1366, 768),0, 32) # use 32-bit color depth
```

Comment: Thank you for the good thorough explanation I learned alot. Unfortunately neither helped, still getting the banding. I did see an error that say "error in original mmap" but not sure what that means.